# Does Yahoo Weather API needs an Consumer API Key?

Tags: ios, api, yahoo, weather

I want to get data from the Weather API to know the forecast of an specific region. 
Using YQL Query I can get an Endpoint URL that returns the information I need, this doesn't seem to require a Consumer Key to work properly.

I want to know if this is legal, and if not, what is the proper way to use my Consumer Key using YQL Query.

This information will be used in an IOS App and as you know it takes over 8 days to be reviewed... The last thing I want is to get my app rejected because of this.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's legal if your app it's not for  commercial purposes "`YQL can be used for commercial purposes, with Yahoo approval.`"

You can use it with or without API Key.
Example:

Hourly Cap

```
- without API Key  - 2,000 requests/hour per IP
- with API Key     - 20,000 requests/hour per IP
```

More info https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I still don't know how to properly send the APIKey, I tried sending it within the allHTTPHeaderFields of my NSMutableURLRequest, but I get an error of Invalid Credentials. 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WEATHER_YQL_URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = @{@"apikey"  :@"myapikey"};