# Yahoo Weather API Key Usage?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, api-key, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

I am planning to develop an iOS weather application that is non-commercial which retrieves JSON feed from Yahoo's Weather API.

Documentation: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

However, I don't understand the purpose of needing an API-Key? I am successful in retrieving weather data by calling this URL with parameters and it gives back a JSON data. *(Note: The URL below is from the JS example but same concept as if it were Objective-C)*

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select wind from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='chicago, il')&format=json&callback=callbackFunction
```

The documentation says non-commercial use is restricted to 2000 queries per day, but how is this tracked if no unique keys were ever used? What is the correct "legal" way in using this API?

I found this old question being asked, however the answer wasn't sufficient: [Does Yahoo Weather API needs an Consumer API Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537353/does-yahoo-weather-api-needs-an-consumer-api-key)

Any input would be appreciated!

**Side Note**
 - Any other FREE weather api tool that do not limit queries and are for non-commercial publication use recommend will also be accepted as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further research, Yahoo offers both a public and OAuth APIs for developers. The public API that is related by querying the URL given above limits users to 2,000 queries per hour per IP Address.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html

Comment: Hi, im using the public api but if i try to request two times in 10 seconds im getting a null weather, is necesary the api key?

Comment: I don't think there's a rate limit besides the 2,000 queries per hour. How are you requesting the JSON feed?

Comment: It seens a problem from yahoo, see thise forum: https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/11869/yql-weather-returning-result-null-half-the-time
https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/12201/yql-weather-result-is-null-in-half-the-time